# Array in sql statement not working with placeholder ?nodejs

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

sql query does not accept array as value when it is used in a placeholder, It only returns one result even though result is greater than 1. Not using a placeholder and withouting escaping it works perfectly returns the right amount of results.

```
//works
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId IN (" + followerIds.join() + ");";
//does not work
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId IN (?);";
con.query(queryFollowerstTable, [followeringIsd.join()],function(err,result)..
```

Comment: What SQL module do you use?

Comment: @Khang I use mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was parse `followerIds.join()` to an int and It worked.

```
followerIdsParsed = followerIds.join().split(',').map(Number);
followingIdsParsed = followingIds.join().split(',').map(Number);
var queryFollowerstTable = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId IN (?); SELECT * 
FROM users WHERE userId IN (?);";
con.query(queryFollowerstTable, [followerIdsParsed, followingIdsParsed], 
function(err, result) {..
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`con.query(queryFollowerstTable, [followeringIds.join()],function(err,result)`
to
`con.query(queryFollowerstTable, followeringIds.join(),function(err,result)`

In your original example:
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId IN (" + followerIds.join() + ");";`

You are passing in a string not an array

Comment: I cannot change it because I am using multistatements in my actual code